# Joining two queries in Propel

Tags: sql, join, propel

I'm rather new to Propel. I am trying to write the following query in Propels object notation:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM  followers WHERE `column1` = 000) AS A
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT * FROM followers WHERE `column1` = 111) AS B
ON A.UserID = B.UserID
WHERE A.UserID IS NULL;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could just use your custom SQL. http://propelorm.org/documentation/03-basic-crud.html#using-custom-sql